# Why does QUERY not read empty cells as 0 in arithmetic functions? And what can I do about it?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The query function calls a range {A:C} where either B or C contains a value while the other an empty cell.

The range is compiled by a script that writes enters the values in rows. I can make the script enter a 0 instead of '', but I want to understand this, and it seems a bit to fragile. It has no effect on when I format the empty cells as numbers.

When my QUERY function in another document calls this range as ...A:C";"select Col1, Col2-Col3") it returns Col1 (A) but no second column, unless I enter a 0 in an empty cell in {A:C}, then that row is calculated by the Query function.

Can I solve this in another way, other than replacing empty cells with 0?

Comment: Can you show your complete query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert empty strings to `0`s with `--(...)` while passing the range to the `QUERY`, numbers will remain as is:

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA({A:A\ --(B:C)});
  "SELECT Col1, Col2 - Col3
   WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL
   LABEL Col2 - Col3 ''
  ";
  0
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer but the code will throw errors. The backslash needs to be replaced with a comma

Comment: @cameronjonesweb depends on your language settings. i thought the guy asking has `;` as delimiter for functions' parameters, and `\` as delimiter for columns